# What is the purpose of the GET method in AsyncTask, does it block the thread?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Seasoned programmer here, but new to Android/Java. I've been learning AsyncTask and think I understand most of the functionality but have a question about the usage of the GET method.

It seems to block the thread whilst waiting for the result. Doesn't that negate the whole point of using AsyncTask? I suspect it must have a purpose that I don't understand.

None of the books or other resources I've read give examples of how/when/if to use it. I understand I can use onPostExecute to get a result set back, and is likely the route I'll take, but I'm wondering what the use case is for get()?

Thanks for any enlightenment.

```
public void button1Clicked(View v){
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> MyTask = new MyTask();
    log("Test 1. About to execute");

    try {
        MyTask.execute();                           // This version returns immediately
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    log("Test 1. Back from execute");
}

public void button2Clicked(View v){
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> MyTask = new MyTask();
    log("Test 2. About to execute");

    try {
        String result = MyTask.execute().get();     // This version waits here, blocking the UI
        log("Result=" + result);

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    log("Test 2. Back from execute");
}

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override protected String doInBackground(Void... params){
        log("doInBackground started");

        try {                           // Sample long running task here
            for(int i=0; i< 3; i++){
                log("Tick: " +i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        log("doInBackground completed");
        return "done";
    }
}

public void log(String message){
    Log.i("DEB:" +Thread.currentThread().getName(), message);
}
```

--- Log when button 1 pressed ---

```
DEB:main: Test 1. About to execute        
DEB:main: Test 1. Back from execute       
DEB:AsyncTask #1: doInBackground started  
DEB:AsyncTask #1: Tick: 0                 
DEB:AsyncTask #1: Tick: 1                 
DEB:AsyncTask #1: Tick: 2                 
DEB:AsyncTask #1: doInBackground completed
```

--- Log when button 2 pressed ---

```
DEB:main: Test 2. About to execute        
DEB:AsyncTask #2: doInBackground started  
DEB:AsyncTask #2: Tick: 0                 
DEB:AsyncTask #2: Tick: 1                 
DEB:AsyncTask #2: Tick: 2                 
DEB:AsyncTask #2: doInBackground completed
DEB:main: Result=done                     
DEB:main: Test 2. Back from execute
```

Comment: Always check official doc before asking the question: [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#get()). It essentially waits for result **if needed**, otherwise returns instantly. There's also overload with optional timeout.

Comment: IIRC, Romain Guy indicated that he regretted adding `get()` to the `AsyncTask` API. Note that `AsyncTask` is fairly obsolete at this point -- modern Android development would use other thread management options (`LiveData` backed by RxJava, Kotlin coroutines, or other stuff).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback folks, much appreciated. I've added RxJava to my learning list. Cheers!